# Accessing uploads offline on my computer

Tags: ebook-readers, ebook-management, android, google-play-books

I use Google Play Books to manage my ebooks.

I have installed the Play Books app as recommended on https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2851654?hl=en-CA to access them offline, but when I launch the apps (or when I go on this address http://books.google.com/ebooks/app), it's written: "No books in this library yet".

I am sure I am in the correct Google Play account, and that I have books there. But all my books in Google Play are personal uploads.

Any idea why it isn't working?

Chrome 39.0
Windows 7